# ajax function which uploads the image and preview it with another string from server

Tags: ajax, file, jsp, servlets, file-upload

I want to use file upload control to upload an image and preview it in same page without submitting the form, is this possible? 
if possible, please let me know how to set the query string of the ajax function, and how to handle that query string at server side. I am using jsp or servlet. 
Intention is to send the image through ajax function call, where I can store the image in server's local folder. also the form will be updated with the part of the result string which is some other component output. Along with this I can show the image which user uploaded. 
1. upload the image through ajax call.
2. return string is do two things, one for shows the image in respective place holder by servers local path and another is to get the other component output which is a string. 
3. if i have that string, I am manipulate at call back function to set the values.
4. after enters users data I want to submit the form finally.

I tried it, but failing to send the file object as parameter to the servlet or jsp. Also if we can send that object, how can we handle that object at jsp?